# Mongo Hadoop Connector Issue

Tags: java, mongodb, hadoop, connector

I am trying to run a MapReduce job: I pull from Mongo and then write to HDFS, but I cannot seem to get the job to run. I could not find an example, but the issues I am having that if I set an input path of Mongo it loos for the output path of Mongo. And now I am getting an authentication error when my MongoDB instance does not have authentication.

```
final Configuration conf = getConf();
final Job job = new Job(conf, "sort");
MongoConfig config = new MongoConfig(conf);
MongoConfigUtil.setInputFormat(getConf(), MongoInputFormat.class);
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path("/trythisdir"));
MongoConfigUtil.setInputURI(conf,"mongodb://localhost:27017/fake_data.file");
//conf.set("mongo.output.uri", "mongodb://localhost:27017/fake_data.file");
job.setJarByClass(imageExtractor.class);
job.setMapperClass(imageExtractorMapper.class);

job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

job.setInputFormatClass( MongoInputFormat.class );

// Execute job and return status
return job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1;
```

Edit: This is the current error I am having:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Couldn't connect and authenticate to get collection
    at com.mongodb.hadoop.util.MongoConfigUtil.getCollection(MongoConfigUtil.java:353)
    at com.mongodb.hadoop.splitter.MongoSplitterFactory.getSplitterByStats(MongoSplitterFactory.java:71)
    at com.mongodb.hadoop.splitter.MongoSplitterFactory.getSplitter(MongoSplitterFactory.java:107)
    at com.mongodb.hadoop.MongoInputFormat.getSplits(MongoInputFormat.java:56)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeNewSplits(JobClient.java:1079)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeSplits(JobClient.java:1096)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.access$600(JobClient.java:177)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:995)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:948)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1408)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:948)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:566)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:596)
    at com.orbis.image.extractor.mongo.imageExtractor.run(imageExtractor.java:103)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at com.orbis.image.extractor.mongo.imageExtractor.main(imageExtractor.java:78)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:208)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.mongodb.MongoURI.<init>(MongoURI.java:148)
    at com.mongodb.MongoClient.<init>(MongoClient.java:268)
    at com.mongodb.hadoop.util.MongoConfigUtil.getCollection(MongoConfigUtil.java:351)
    ... 22 more
```

Comment: Could you show us the concrete error messages?

Comment: I added the stack trace to the question

Comment: I have the same issue Kevin.  Could you tell me how did you resolve this?

Comment: Hey Vaibhav. I was never able to solve this issue and had to write a non mapreduce solution.

Answer (score 2):

Late answer.. It may be helpul for people. I encountered with same problem while playing with Apache Spark.

I think you should set correctly mongo.input.uri and mongo.output.uri which will be used by hadoop and also input and output formats.

```
/*Correct input and output uri setting on spark(hadoop)*/
conf.set("mongo.input.uri", "mongodb://localhost:27017/dbName.inputColName");
conf.set("mongo.output.uri", "mongodb://localhost:27017/dbName.outputColName");

/*Set input and output formats*/
job.setInputFormatClass( MongoInputFormat.class );
job.setOutputFormatClass( MongoOutputFormat.class )
```

Btw, if "mongo.input.uri" or "mongo.output.uri" strings have typos it causes same error.

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
MongoConfigUtil.setInputURI(conf, "mongodb://localhost:27017/fake_data.file");
```

by:

```
MongoConfigUtil.setInputURI(job.getConfiguration(), "mongodb://localhost:27017/fake_data.file");
```

The conf object is already 'consumed' by your job, so you need to set it directly on the configuration of the job.

Comment: This has helped! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shared the complete code so it's hard to tell, but what you've got there does not look consistent with typical usage of the MongoDB Connector for Hadoop.

I would suggest that you start with the [examples](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop/tree/master/examples) in github.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but I have tried the examples and they worked correctly but the issue is that these examples move data from mongodb to mongodb.

Comment: Please share the full source of your classes then.